# Unacceptable TLS certificate- When trying to install the MonoDevelop Flat Pak

Tags: linux, git, mono

After installing FlatPak and following the instructions to install MonoDevelop [here](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/)

The Command I run is: `sudo flatpak install --user --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref`

But the error I receive is:

> Can't load uri
>   https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref:
>   Unacceptable TLS certificate

Is this a problem with thier site that they need to fix? or is there something I can do on my machine.

My OS is Peppermint 7 based on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is for  *.vo.msecnd.net

The domain the certificate is delivered on is

download.mono-project.com

They bound the wrong certificate to the wrong domain.

You can't fix this, only send a bug report/issue ticket to their website maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

This may be not as secure as using the https option, but this is what I did to solve the problem. I downloaded the file monodevelop.flatpakref, and using a text editor I opened it and edited the Url line from https://... to http://...
That did the magic. To install I used the command `sudo flatpak install --user monodevelop.flatpakref` in the location where I saved the file.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get error: Invalid .flatpakrepo: key file contains line "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC - ..."